# Не найдена функция doAsync (подсвечивается красным)

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx-coroutines, jetbrains-anko

Функция `doAsync` не вызывается? Я импортировал библиотеку Anko, но все равно не вызывается. Красным подсвечивается `doAsync`.

**Build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.13"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8"
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.weather

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.weather.R.id.result_info

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var user_filed: EditText? = null
    private var main_btn: Button? = null
    private var result_info: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        user_filed = findViewById(R.id.user_filed)
        main_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_text)
        result_info = findViewById(R.id.result_info)

        main_btn?.setOnClickListener {
            if (user_filed?.text?.toString()?.trim()?.equals("")!!) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter City", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                var city: String = user_filed?.text.toString()
               введите сюда код var key: String = "34ad38945d9iibb42c99ef4180e7f88c4"
                var url: String =
                    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=$key&units=metric&lang=ru"

                doAsync { //Красным подсвечивается
                    
                }
                

            }

        }
    }}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `doAsync` это наверное что-то очень старое, подключите корутины ([kotlinx-coroutines-core](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#using-in-your-projects)) и используйте функцию [`async`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html). Кроме этого, на всякий случай предупреждаю вас, что Anko уже устарела и [не поддерживается](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md). Вместо нее есть крутой [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose).

Comment: спс за инфу, помог!

Comment: @CrakDos, оформил как ответ, если ок, то можете его засчитать.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо использования устаревшего `doAsync`, подключите [`kotlinx-coroutines-core`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#using-in-your-projects) и используйте метод [`async`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
}
```

Кроме этого, имейте ввиду, что библиотека Anko уже устарела и с 2019 года больше [не поддерживается](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md). Вместо нее посмотрите на [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) — это очень крутой и мощный инструмент для построения пользовательского интерфейса.